# Failed to configure Realm builder in gradle 3.0.0 beta2

Tags: android, realm

I am using `realm database` to maintain product log in my app.! my app getting a crash while configuring realm builder.! I used the following code to configure the realm builder.

```
RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(AddProductItems.this).build();
realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);
realmHelper = new RealmHelper(realm);
```

I have also tried this code too.

```
realm = Realm.getInstance(MyActivity.this);
```

I am still getting the same error.I am using `Android Studio 3.0 beta 2` and `3.0.0-beta2 of gradle version`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "come.ajay.bill"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    provided 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
    annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'

}
```

gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here i add my console log

[image]

Comment: Show your other Gradle file as well  and the applied plugins

Comment: @EpicPandaForce check now.! i update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> provided 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'

That won't work because that means you're not actually including Realm in your code (which is why you're getting the error you're getting).

In AS 3.0, `provided` should be replaced by `compileOnly`

However in your case, it should be

```
implementation 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
```

(I hope that works, because there is a chance you'll just get the following error - I have not tested this:

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>
> Alternatively, set `android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true` to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>     See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

)

---

It's worth noting that Realm 0.88.0 to 2.1.1 does NOT support `annotationProcessor` scope yet (only `apt` scope, which is NOT supported by AS 3.0!) if you use `apply plugin: 'realm-android'`, in which case you'd need to manually do what the Realm Gradle Plugin does in the background (add the right dependencies + register the RealmTransformer task)

---

Also worth noting that the latest version at this time is Realm-Java **5.7.0**, which is much newer than 0.87.5.

Comment: thanks.!It was helpful.Actually, i am not aware of latest version.!I just came from few tutorials.! let me go with latest versions with the help of latest docs.! thanks @EpicPandaForce